# Loading scripts with wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

How could I include the following script and stylesheet in a wordpress plugin if they only need to load in the admin panel?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/chosen.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook

Answer (score 1):

There are probably various ways to do this – personally I use the following for loading some small scripts only on the "new" and "edit" pages (datepicker etc.):

```
function load_my_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    if (( $hook == 'post.php' || $hook == 'post-new.php' )) {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-datepicker', // name / handle of the script
        SCRIPTS . 'script.js', // path to the script
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), // array of registered handles this script depends on
        '1.0', // script version number (optional)
        true // enqueue the script before </head>
    );

    }

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_admin_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_admin_script_wpse_217608() {
    $assets_path = plugins_url('assets/', __FILE__);

    wp_enqueue_style('chosen-style', $assets_path . 'chosen.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('chosen-script', $assets_path . 'chosen.jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_script_wpse_217608' );
```

Where `$assets_path` is the path to your assets folder.

**Edit**: Props to @cale_b for using `plugins_url()` to avoid confusion and hard coded strings.

Comment: Close.  Use the Wordpress function for getting the plugin folder url, instead of hard-coding the path.  See 'plugins_url'

Comment: @cale_b that's the best scenario. No hardcoded stuff.

Comment: Yeah you missed my point: change your answer to include the usage of plugin_url - otherwise this answer suggests bad practices.

Comment: The only reason for me to use it like this was to illustrate what to put there instead of a comment. I can't see a problem assigning `plugin_url` to it and just use it instead of writing `plugin_url` twice. That's why I've left it like this in the first place. Also I am not sure what folder structure is he using.

Comment: You still miss my point: Mention it.  Show an example of how to use it properly.  This answer, as it sits, suggest the user should hard-code the path to the script.  You and I both know you should not, so make your answer **good**.  (Then I'll be inclined to upvote it!)

Comment: Yes you have perfectly valid point. I've edited the answer to avoid confusion. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I first added

```
function __construct() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'xsmi_load_admin_script' ) );
...
```

since it's in a class.

And the function...

```
function xsmi_load_admin_script() {
wp_register_style( 'chosencss', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.css', __FILE__ ), true, '', 'all' );
wp_register_script( 'chosenjs', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'chosencss' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'chosenjs' );
}
```

The `true` at the end of `wp_register_script` loads it in the footer. This is the only way I could get it to work. That for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't exeute anything in the class constructor. That is not what constructors are meant to do. You should remove your action from the constructor ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. I'll go look up the purpose of the class constructor.

Comment: I thought all WP hooks and filters had to be registered in the constructor when building a plugin as a class. The action throws and error when I place it outside of the constructor. I'm going off of this: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/create-wordpress-plugins-with-oop-techniques--net-20153